# Search for a related json data

Tags: javascript, json

How can i find data that is related to the already known data?
( I'm a newb. )

For example here is my json :

```
[ 
{ "id": "1",  "log": "1","pass":  "1111" },
{ "id": 2,  "log": "2","pass":  "2222" },
{ "id": 3, "log": "3","pass":  "3333" }
]
```

Now i know that `"log"` is `1` and i  want to find out the data `"pass"` that is related to it.

i've tried to do it so :

The POST request comes with `log` and `pass` data , i search the .json file for the same `log`  value and if there is the same data then i search for related `pass`

```
fs.readFile("file.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {

                var jsonFileArr = []; 
                jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data);  // Parse .json objekts

                var log = loginData.log; // The 'log' data that comes with POST request

               /* Search through .json file for the same data*/

               var gibtLog = jsonFileArr.some(function (obj) {
                 return obj.log == log;
                });


                if (gotLog) { // If there is the same 'log'

                    var pass = loginData.pass; // The 'pass' data that comes with POST request

                  var gotPass = jsonFileArr.some(function (obj) {
                    // How to change this part ?
                    return obj.pass == pass;
                });

                }
                else
                    console.log("error");

            });
```

The problem is that when i use

```
var gotPass = jsonFileArr.some(function (obj) {
                 return obj.pass == pass;
                });
```

it searches through the whole .json file and not through only one objekt.

Comment: Can there be more than one item with the same `log` value?

Comment: @nnnnnn, it is always one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that `.some()` returns a *boolean*, whether any of the elements match your predicate or not, but not the element itself.

You want `.find()` (which will find and return the first element matching the predicate):

```
const myItem = myArray.find(item => item.log === "1"); // the first matching item
console.log(myItem.pass); // "1111"
```

Note that it is possible for `.find()` to not find anything, in which case it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks , that works! Just a small question , in this part  `.find(obj => obj `  i get  "Expected expression" error message , does it mean that i use old ES version ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. The `(args) => expression` syntax is called "Arrow function" and it's there from approximately Node 4.

Answer (score 2):

The `.some()` method returns a boolean that just tells you whether there is at least one item in the array that matches the criteria, it doesn't return the matching item(s). Try [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead:

```
   var jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data);

   var log = loginData.log;

   var matchingItems = jsonFileArr.filter(function (obj) {
     return obj.log == log;
   });

   if (matchingItems.length > 0) {     // Was at least 1 found?
     var pass = matchingItems[0].pass; // The 'pass' data that comes with the first match
   } else
     console.log("error");             // no matches
```

Comment: Thank you that works!! But the first answer work too , what should i do ? :)

Comment: Accept whichever you prefer, and if you have no preference I'd just accept the other one because it was posted first.

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is probably the easiest, but you could also do (among other things)

```js
const x = [{
  "id": "1",
  "log": "1",
  "pass": "1111"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "log": "2",
  "pass": "2222"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "log": "3",
  "pass": "3333"
}];
let myItem;
for (let item of x) {
  if (item.log === '1') {
    myItem = item;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(myItem);
```

Comment: Thank you for this example!